# Formulário HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um teste e preciso fazer um formulário padrão de "trabalhe conosco", com envio de currículo..
Preciso saber como validar esse formulário e fazer com que ele receba arquivos..

```
<form>
<label>Nome*:</label>
<input class="nome" type="text"></br>
<label>Email:</label>
<input class="email" type="password"></br>
<label>UF:</label>
<input class="uf">
<label>Cidade:</label></br>
<input class="cidade" type="text">
<label>Mensagem:</label></br><textarea class="msg" cols="35" rows="8"></textarea></br>
<input class="bnt_submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Pesquise sobre o PHPMailer

Comment: Claro.. estou com duvido sobre oque devo usar pra isso.. é Jquery, PHP.. ?

Comment: vc vai precisar de um backend para o caso do upload de arquivo. E para validar vc pode usar desde a validação do html. Eu sugiro que vc tente com js ou com jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, cara. O html e o css vão está na máquina de quem está acessando seu site, ou seja, lá no navegador, podemos dizer que eles estão rodando no cliente. Porém, se você deseja pegar os dados que o cliente está trabalhando você precisa de uma plicação servidor que vai receber estes dados, isso pode ser feito em php, node, python, etc.

Se você está começando a estudar isso agora, aconselho a usar o php, pois a comunidade ainda é a maior. Assim que decidir qual usar, você pode jogar passar as informações do cliente para o servidor usando o atributo `action="meuphp.php"` da tag form do html. Para pegar os dados nesse arquivo use a variável `$_GET["cidade"]` por exemplo. O nome dentro do get deve ser o name do seu input.
Para fazer upload com html, use:

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload">
```

Comment: Muitooo obrigada. Tu já me deu um norte bem grande hahaha.

Comment: Qualquer coisa, só perguntar.

Answer (score -3):

Formulario


    
    
        Cadastro de DEVs
        Complete suas informações

```
<!-- Início do formulário -->
<form id="form">
    <!-- Campo do nome com legenda "nome" e css de classe "campo" -->
    <fieldset class="grupo">
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="nome"><strong>Nome</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required>
        </div>

        <!-- Campo do sobrenome com legenda "sobrenome" e css de classe "campo" -->
        <div class="campo">
            <label><strong>Sobrenome</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" required>
        </div>            
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="grupo">
        <!-- Campo de email-->
        <div class="campo">
            <label><strong>Email</strong></label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        </div>

        <!-- Campo de CPF-->
        <div class="campo">
            <label><strong>CPF</strong></label>
            <input type="text" id="identification" required>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Campo de Data de nascimento-->
    <div class="campo">
        <label for="data_nascimento"><b>Data de Nascimento:</b></label>
            <input type="date" name="data_nascimento" id="data_nascimento" required>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Campo de desenvolvimento web com 3 opções de botões selecionáveis (radio button)-->
    <div class="campo">
        <label><strong>De qual lado da aplicação você desenvolve?</strong></label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="devweb" value="frontend" checked>Front-end
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="devweb" value="backend">Back-end
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="devweb" value="fullstack">Fullstack
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Campo de senioridade com 3 opções para escolha (select option)-->
    <div class="campo">
        <label for="senioridade"><strong>Senioridade</strong></label>
        <select id="senioridade" required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Selecione</option>
            <option>Junior</option>
            <option>Pleno</option>
            <option>Senior</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <fieldset class="grupo">
        <!-- Campo de tecnologias para escolha de 1 ou mais opções para marcar (checkbox) -->
        <div id="check">
            <label><strong>Selecione as tecnologias que utiliza:</strong></label><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tecnologia1" name="tecnologias[]" value="HTML" checked>
            <label for="tecnologia1">HTML</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tecnologia2" name="tecnologias[]" value="CSS">
            <label for="tecnologia2">CSS</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tecnologia3" name="tecnologias[]" value="Javascript">
            <label for="tecnologia3">Javascript</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tecnologia4" name="tecnologias[]" value="PHP">
            <label for="tecnologia4">PHP</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tecnologia5" name="tecnologias[]" value="C#">
            <label for="tecnologia5">C#</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tecnologia6" name="tecnologias[]" value="Python">
            <label for="tecnologia6">Python</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tecnologia7" name="tecnologias[]" value="Java">
            <label for="tecnologia7">Java</label>
        </div>  
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Caixa de texto -->
    <div class="campo">
        <br>
        <label><strong>Conte um pouco da sua experiência:</strong></label>
        <textarea rows="6" style="width: 26em" id="experiencia" name="experiencia" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Botão para enviar o formulário -->
    <button class="botao" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="enviar()">Concluído</button>
</form>

<script src="./formulario.js"></script>
```

---

//css
/* Todos os elementos da página */

- {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

/* Elementos com o ID "titulo" */
#titulo {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #181717;
margin-left: 7%;
}

/* Elementos com o ID "subtitulo" */
#subtitulo {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #2e2d2d;
margin-left: 10%;
}

#check{
display: inline-block;
}

/* Elementos de tag */
fieldset {
border: 0;
}

/* Elemento de tag  */
body{
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(87, 98, 105), rgb(222, 236, 242));
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
color: #131313;
margin-left: 36%;
margin-top: 2%;
justify-content: center;
}

/* Elementos de tags , , ,  e  */
input, select, textarea, button {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
color: #151516;
border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Elementos de classe "grupo" nos estados das pseudoclasses "before" e "after" */
.grupo:before, .grupo:after {
display: table;
}

/* Elementos de classe "grupo" no estado da pseudoclasse "after" */
.grupo:after {
clear: both;
}

/* Elementos de classe "campo" */
.campo {
margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/* Elementos de classe "campo" de tag  */
.campo label {
margin-bottom: 0.2em;
color: #1c1c1e;
display: block;
}

/* Elementos de classe "campo" ou "grupo" de tag  */
fieldset.grupo .campo {
float:  left;
margin-right: 1em;
}

/* Elementos de classe "campo" das tags  com atributo text e email, da tag  e da tag */
.campo input[type="text"], .campo input[type="email"], .campo select, .campo textarea {
padding: 0.2em;
border: 1px solid #000000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 251, 251, 0.2);
display: block;
}

/* Elementos de classe "campo" de tag  e */
.campo select option {
padding-right: 1em;
}

/* Elemento de classe "campo" com tag ,  e  tocas com estado da pseudoclasse "focus"*/
.campo input:focus, .campo select:focus, .campo textarea:focus {
background: #ffffff;
}

/* Elemento de classe "botao" */
.botao {
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(176, 40, 40), rgb(38, 36, 40));
width: 50%;
border: none;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Elemento de classe "botao" com o estado da pseudoclasse "hover" */
.botao:hover {
background: #89888a;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
text-shadow: none;
}

/* Elementos de classe botão e de tag  */
.botao, select{
cursor: pointer;
}

................

//js
document.getElementById('identification').addEventListener('input', function (e) {

let x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,2})/);
e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '.' : '') + x[3] + (x[4] ? '/' : x[4]) + x[4] + (x[5] ? '-' + x[5] : '');

if (e.target.value.length < 15) {
x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})/);
e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '.' : '') + x[3] + (x[4] ? '-' + x[4] : '');
}

console.log('formatação: ' + e.target.value);
});

Comment: //head
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formulario.css" media="">